# Where to grant an account permissions for event log

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, permissions, windows-event-log

My asp.net application does not have the permission to write to windows event log. It is running under Network Service account. Is there any tool/management console rather than hack in the registry to guaranty the permission? Thanks!

Btw. I'm using Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score -2):

[How To: Use Impersonation and Delegation in ASP.NE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx)T